# Camel: TransformerException: Extension function: '{}' can not be invoked when the XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING feature is set to true

Tags: xslt, apache-camel, xalan

I have a stylesheet that uses some xalan dates-and-times extentions. The stylesheet was unittested fine with Xalan. However, when running through a Camel route I'm getting:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extension function: '{http://exslt.org/dates-and-times}date-time' can not be invoked when the XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING feature is set to true.

Is there any way out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try turning off the secure processing feature. See: [TransformerFactory.html.setFeature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setFeature-java.lang.String-boolean-)

If you have access to the Java code that runs your XSLT processor:

```
TransformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
```

Comment: That would have been great but unfortunately camel instantiates its own factory instance.

Comment: You can override the default `TransformerFactory` which has that restriction by configuring your endpoint. See [xslt: component](http://camel.apache.org/xslt). Something like `from(...).to("xslt:your-template.xslt?transformerFactory=bean")` or `<to uri="xslt:your-template.xsl?transformerFactory=bean"/>` where `bean` is the reference to your non-secured transformer factory. You can also use this to replace Xalan with Saxon for XSLT 2.0 support.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Also found the same answer here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.camel.user/15776