# java.lang.RuntimeException: Use of the extension function is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true

Tags: java, spring-boot, xslt, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an .xsl file in which external functions are called. When I run the program, I get the following error:

> Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use of the extension function '....' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true.
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:791) ~[na:na]
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:397) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltBuilder.process(XsltBuilder.java:123) ~[camel-xslt-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.support.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:93) ~[camel-support-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.onExchange(XsltEndpoint.java:117) ~[camel-xslt-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.support.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:61) ~[camel-support-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:217) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:111) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:108) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:190) ~[camel-support-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.request(DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.java:386) ~[camel-base-engine-3.13.0.jar:3.13.0]
> ... 42 common frames omitted

This is the called code:

> String result = producerTemplate.to("xslt:" + xslt))
> .withBody(inputVariable).withHeaders(variables).request(String.class);

I want to set the secure processing to false, but I am not sure how to do that as it seems to be handled by Camel entirely, any suggestions?

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706831/camel-transformerexception-extension-function-can-not-be-invoked-when-th

Comment: I get the idea, the links are unfortunately broken there :(